# SSRS parameter click not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

When I try to choose a value from my parameters in SSRS, the dropdown list just shuts down and I can't choose anything. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: If you can add as much detail as possible it will help people answer. Are the options for your parameter specific values, or values from a query? In which version of Internet Explorer do your experience the issue? Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: I have tried other browsers like chrome and it works, the thing is when I click the scroll bar the dropdown list disappears. The version of IE is 10. The values are from a query.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: I use the 2016 version

Comment: I've noticed this too.  I think it has something to do with applying possible values with a query.  I have to use the mousewheel or arrowkeys, unfortunately.  Alternatively, the SSRS report can be previewed in Visual Studio and it will work as expected, no problem.